# If $\mathbf A$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf B$, then $\mathbf B$ is a multiple of $\mathbf A$. True or false?

Tags: linear-algebra

Actually, I couldn't understand the question. Can you explain? ''If $\mathbf A$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf B$, then $\mathbf B$ is a multiple of $\mathbf A$. True or false?''

Comment: Consider the scalar $0$.

Comment: @Bungo Then, **B= 0** ?

Comment: Are *A* and **A** distinct quantities?

Comment: One possible reason for misunderstanding is that it could have been better stated: ".... then $\mathbf B$ is a **scalar** multiple of $\mathbf A$."

Comment: @LeeMosher  **A** and **B** are vectors. Then, how did **scalar** become?

Comment: Just to be clear about what may be in doubt, the phrase "$\mathbf A$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf B$" means "there exists a scalar $c$ such that ${\mathbf A} = c \mathbf B$".

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's true if the scalar by which $A$ is multiplied by $B$ has a multiplicative inverse.

It won't work if that scalar is $0$.

If in some context you wanted to construe "scalar" to mean an *integer* (which I suspect some mathematicians may do sometimes) then only $\pm1$ would have multiplicative inverses, but typically "scalar" will mean a real or complex number or element of some other *field*, and in *fields* everything except $0$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: "which I suspect some mathematicians may do sometimes" Yes, extension/restriction of scalars is a thing in module theory. It can be even any ring not just the integers.

Comment: @quid : I wasn't actually sure they called them "scalars" in that case, but I'm not surprised. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy The question is from Linear Algebra Through Geometry ,Wermer and Banchoff. Probably, there is a eror since in the text, it was written ''If *A* is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf B$, then $\mathbf B$ is a multiple of $\mathbf A$. (?)

Comment: In a book like that, "scalar" would normally mean real number, unless it means complex number, or unless you're doing a problem in which it says for the duration of the problem it means something else.  But are you saying the typeface for the letter $A$ was different in the two places where it appeared? $\qquad$

Comment: @Kahler Is there something else known about $A;B$. When $A$ and $B$ are non-zero for example then the scalar must also be non-zero, and it becomes true. Really the only exception is that $0$ is a scalar multiple of everything while nothing non-zero is a multiple of $0$. (That is in the case scalars are from a field which is likely given your context.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy *A* should be **A** in the text, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Kahler : Certainly it should have the same typeface both times.